# How to create a function in JS and implement in TMPL file

Tags: javascript, templates

- Hi all, How to create a function in JS and implement in TMPL file?
- I have a code that my input is XML and the output is XML SOAP
  _ for now all the code under is working good
- In test tag in the TMPL file instead 0 I want the result the multiple of B1 and B2 for example. thx.

**my code:**

XML Input for example:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-16"?>
<A>
 <B1>123</B1>
 <B2>456</B2>
</A>
```

JS:

```
var testJSVMData = new TykJS.TykMiddleware.NewMiddleware({});

testJSVMData.NewProcessRequest(function(request, session, config) {

log(JSON.stringify(request.Headers));
log(JSON.stringify(request.Body));
//log(JSON.stringify(request));

log(typeof(request.Body));

return testJSVMData.ReturnData(request, {});
});
```

TMPL:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
 <env:Envelope xmlns:env="http://bla.com" xmlns ="bla.com" >
 <env:Header>
    <p:Messaging schemaVersion="1.0" xmlns:p="bla.com">
        <UserMessage>
            <MessageInfo>
                <Source>bla1</Source>
                <Destination>bla2</Destination>
                <MessageId>{{.A.B1}}</MessageId>
            </MessageInfo>
        </UserMessage>
    </p:Messaging>
</env:Header>
<env:Body>
        <test>0</test>
</env:Body>
</env:Envelope>
```